# how to override the DataSourceFactory for database connection pooling in apache-tomee-jaxrs-1.5.2

Tags: java, factory-pattern, apache-tomee

i have set the data source properties in tomee.xml file and its work fine.
my tomee.xml file

```
  <Resource id="jdbc/myrootdb" type="DataSource">
   JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver    
   JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
   UserName test
   Password NqM2MyOjKGqI+4456k9azQw===
   PasswordCipher Static3DES
   DataSourceCreator dbcp
   JtaManaged false   
   InitialSize 50 
   MaxActive 100
    MaxIdle 3
 </Resource>
```

This is working without any problem even i encrypted the password using openEjb but problem is that any user can decrypt the password easily using openejb so i need that the only password properties i will push or set from the my java class or my factory.so what is the way i can override this datasource.